# Confused by docs and source of CountedCompleter

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, forkjoinpool

Here is a code fragment of `java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter` class (JDK 1.8.0_25).

```
/**
 * If the pending count is nonzero, decrements the count;
 * otherwise invokes {@link #onCompletion(CountedCompleter)}
 * and then similarly tries to complete this task's completer,
 * if one exists, else marks this task as complete.
 */
public final void tryComplete() {
    CountedCompleter<?> a = this, s = a;
    for (int c;;) {
        if ((c = a.pending) == 0) {
            a.onCompletion(s);
            if ((a = (s = a).completer) == null) {
                s.quietlyComplete();
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(a, PENDING, c, c - 1))
            return;
    }
}
```

It makes me really confused. The documentation says: "and then similarly tries to complete this task's completer", but I do not see any invocations of 'complete' on this task's completer; or any other calls to it.

Have anybody worked with this class? Is it an issue with documentation or implementation? I might also cook it in a wrong way. Any ideas how to properly deal with this class is appreciated.

Comment: I guess, it's all thanks to `a = (s=a).completer` assignments and then doing `a.onCompletion(...)` on next iteration of loop.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it should be done there; though 'onCompletion' is void and empty by default, so it may be not so easy and straight to implement join-like completion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're confused? Everyone is confused. I've been writing a critique on the F/J framework for four years now and I can tell you the level of complexity is reaching the critical level with 8u40. The reason this class exists at all is because the join() [doesn't work](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html#faulty). In order to get around the stalling threads for Java8 streams the architect invented this class.

The way you work this class is you addToPendingCount() for every fork(). In the compute(), when done, you tryComplete(). When the count is zero, the method calls your onCompletion(). A bit messy but if your code is simple, it works.

The rest of the code you see is for when the current CountedCompleter has a chain of CountedCompleter objects of its own. My guess is this is probably for the parallel.stream processing.

Comment: Hello @edharned, would it be possible to remove your personal opinion from this answer - although it is a bit old.

Comment: @ Kineolyan The Class is confusing, even Doug Lea says so in the JavaDoc. This isn't just my option. As of Apr 30, 2015 the parallel stream code hadn't been finalized. Now that it has my guess was accurate. Exactly what part offends you?

Comment: Hello @edharned, I cannot say I am offended. I just think it would be best to first give the answer to the question. Then, as a side node, you can inform that this F/J framework is confusing, that you wrote critique about it, ... But it should focus on the answer first.

Comment: @Kineolyan OK, next time I'll consider that. For now I cannot change such an old (over two years) answer.